# How to read two strings separated by ":" in c

Tags: c, string, file, scanf

I need to know how to read a string and split in two as in the example below.

i have this string in a file @amanda:@bruna, but i can't read as separate words, and each store in two diferent variables like this:

```
char userA[20];
char userB[20];
scanf("%s:%s", userA, userB);
```

Can you help me?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/   `%s` reads any number of non-whitespace characters, which `:` most definitely isn't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a scanset to prevent the first `%s` consuming the entire line, as the `%s` will only stop consuming when it encounters whitespace:

```
if (scanf("%19[^:]:%19s", userA, userB) == 2)
{
    /* 'userA' and 'userB' have been successfully assigned. */
}
```

where `%19[^:]` means *read at most 19 characters but stop when a colon is encountered*. Specifying the width prevets buffer overrun. Always check the result of [`scanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), which returns the number of assignments made, to ensure subsequent code is not processing stale or uninitialized variables.

Comment: @user1769712, no problem at all. I learned about scansets on stackoverflow also, very useful (both scansets and SO!).

Answer (score 1):

```
char buf[60];
char userA[20];
char userB[20];
char *ptr;

scanf("%s", buf);
ptr = strchr(buf, ':');
if (ptr == NULL)
{
  // whatever you want to do if there's no ':'
}
*ptr = 0;
strcpy(userA, buf);
strpcy(userB, ptr + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use `scanf`.  (Indeed, outside of university classes, `scanf` has almost no purpose).  Just read the data:

```
int main( void )
{
  char line[ 80 ];
  char *userA, *userB;
  fgets( line, sizeof line, stdin );  /* Need to check that a full line was read */
  userA = line;
  userB = strchr( line, ':' );  /* Need to check that the input contains a colon */
  *userB++ = '\0';
```